# PHP chmod( ):Operation not permitted, safe_mode deprecation involved?

Tags: php, apache, file-permissions, chmod, virtualmin

I'm struggling a bit to grasp the concept of `chmod()` from PHP as the course I'm currently taking is a bit outdated and involves safe_mode. It states that as safe_mode is turned off, the restrictions to modify permissions with `chmod()` to a file when the owner is not the same as the one executing the command are removed. I'm working with PHP 5.5.9 in conjuncture with XAMPP, I've verified that the flags are turned off (just in case), but can't seem to get it working. As I execute the following PHP script:

```
echo "File permissions :" .  decoct(fileperms("file_permissions.php"));
chmod("file_permissions.php" ,0777);
```

I receive the following output :

```
Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted
```

My permissions for the file are the following

```
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 joelhernandez  staff     24 Apr 14 06:59 file_permissions.php
```

And I've executed `ps aux | grep httpd` to confirm that the **my webserver is operating under the user "daemon" .**

As I change the file ownership to **daemon**:

```
-rwxrwxrwx@  1 daemon  staff     24 Apr 14 06:59 file_permissions.php
```

Everything works, I do not understand why as I had understood that with safe_mode turned off, file ownership would mean nothing, instead file permissions were the way to handle access.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `daemon` user is not `root`, so it is not allowed to change the mode of a file owned by a different user. PHP safe_mode is not the cause here. The warning is telling you that the attempted operation failed because the web server user did not have permission to make the mode change.

The operation succeeded after you manually changed the ownership of the file to `daemon` because users are allowed to change the mode of files they own.

Comment: Alright, so what approach should I take ? Isn't safe_mode by being off would allow change of permissions in files that users don't own? Also, I believe I read that chmod() did not required super user permissions, only chown()

Comment: `chmod` doesn't always require root - users can change the mode of files they own - `joelhernandez` can change the mode of files owned by `joelhernandez`, and `daemon` can change the mode of files owned by `daemon`. Users (other than root) cannot change the mode of files they do not own - `daemon` cannot change the mode of files owned by `joelhernandez`.

Comment: As for what you should do instead, it's hard to say without knowing more about what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: The comment I up voted solved my doubt! Thanks, I guess the tutorial wasn't pretty straightforward about it!

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem by changing the owernship of the file. Still can't figure out why the root user or general user is not permitted to modify or create a file or directory within the same direcory despite changing file ownership to all

```
sudo chown -R daemon:daemon /opt/lampp/htdocs/html/directory/
```