# PHP - chmod(): Operation not permitted

Tags: php, apache, centos, codeigniter-3, chmod

I have files that owned by root and I want to change it permission with php using `chmod()`. But it gave me an error `chmod(): Operation not permitted` instead.

```
if (file_exists($filepath)) {
    chmod($filepath, 0755);
}
```

[PHP Error Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyGfR.png)

[image: 2]

How to use `chmod()` in php but the files ownership are root ?
Can I achieve this without changing files ownership ?

Application Environment:

- PHP 7.1.33
- Code Igniter 3 framework
- Apache 2.4.6
- CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003

Any answer are appreciated, thanks before.

**EDIT:**

I've run `ps aux | grep httpd` and it shows only root and apache on the list.

[image: 1]

Comment: Are you running the php file via the command line "cli" or in the browser with apache/nginx?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP chmod( ):Operation not permitted, safe\_mode deprecation involved?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070266/php-chmod-operation-not-permitted-safe-mode-deprecation-involved)

Comment: @JordanCasey Im using it in the browser with apache

Comment: @chiliNUT Thanks for the info, I've run ps aux | grep httpd and there is only root and apache on the list, what's that mean ?

Comment: The file is owned by root, so you can't change it by apache user.

Comment: @shingo thanks for the info. if that so, is there a way to change the ownership programmatically using PHP ? thanks before.

Comment: No unless PHP is running by root, but this is dangerous. https://askubuntu.com/questions/116144/how-do-i-run-apache-as-root

Answer (score -3, accepted):

As the files are owned by root and not www-data, apache will not have permissions to change the file's read and write permissions. You would need to set the folder to be owned and writable by www-data.

The command in centOS for doing so is

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache ./filepath
```

You would need sudo for the root owner as well as replace filepath with your folder's name

Comment: I've run it but it says `chown: invalid user: 'www-data:www-data'`

And does that mean I need to change the ownership of the file to www-data each time a new file stored to the same folder by root ?

Comment: i'm sorry, www-data is a debian user. You would need to use httpd:httpd and yes it does mean if you're storing files by hand that if you want chmod to work, they will need to belong to httpd

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer, I've run it again but still it says `chown: invalid user: 'httpd:httpd'`. Sorry, am I missing something ?

Comment: By the way, can I achieve that without changing the ownership or maybe can I change the ownership programmatically using PHP when the files belongs to root ?

Comment: you can run this to figure out who the apache user is ```ps aux | egrep '(apache|httpd)'``` then chown to that user. If you wanted to change the group ownership you could, It just leaves security a bit less strict so I do not do this. If the fire belongs to root, then root and SUDOers are the only ones that can change this. You could run a cron as root to change the permissions but again not secure. If someone injects a php or bash file to your location, it would be a bad time