# Php Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted

Tags: php, chmod

I have an error with php function chmod https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php Any solutions?
I'm running Linux Debian 13.05 with root access and PHP 8.2.
Php Warning: chmod(): No such file or directory in file: index.php on line: 8
After I added a empty file, I we get:

> Php Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in file: index.php on line: 8
> Php Warning: fopen(./access.log): Failed to open stream: Permission denied in file: index.php on line: 9

```
$root_path = './'; define('LOG_FILE', $root_path . 'access.log');

function add_log_entry($access = '')
{
    if (LOG_FILE)
    {
        chmod(LOG_FILE, 0755);
        $fopen = fopen(LOG_FILE, 'ab');
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to chmod a file, that does not even exist at that point.

Comment: `Warning: fopen(./access.log): Failed to open stream: Permission denied` - was the chmod call your attempt to fix this error? If the file did not even exist up to that point - then you should perhaps go and check the write permission for the _folder_ first of all.

Comment: The function is more complex but how is there if I add access.log  we get: Php Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in file: index.php on line: 8

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74440569/1427878

Comment: The question yet stands: Why chmod() was added to PHP if we need to run the command in a console or via ftp ? If I remember correct there is a way to get administration privileges before we use the command chmod() but is not added to a manual online on php.net were I showed the link above.

Comment: Not, that question never stood to begin with, because it makes absolutely no sense. It was added to PHP, so that you can change file access rights - no more, no less. That it of course MUST NOT allow you to change any rights _beyond_ what the same user could do on the command line, should be absolutely obvious - if PHP's chmod _allowed_ to do more, that would be a security hole. _"If I remember correct there is a way to get administration privileges before we use the command chmod()"_ - you mean `sudo` or something?

Comment: There is a www directory were the webmaster via php shoud be allowed to test all the build in functions.

Comment: Normally the webserver account should not be able to write to the www directory - that's a security risk (because of code injection possibilities). Maybe test on a different folder, outside the website root.

Answer (score 1):

This is working if the directory and file is created by same user in '/var/www/myphpapp/' and from same user group and can be continued until there that we do not need to use 'sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/myphpapp' nor ftp chmod command.
Another solution on Linux is to use a subdirectory in our own '/home/user/www/' directory, or in '/root/www/' for given example, and this can be simplified.

```
$root_path = './'; 
define('LOG_FILE', $root_path . 'access.log');
    
    function add_log_entry($access = '')
    {
        if (LOG_FILE)
        {
            // Default to write
            $perms = 2;
            
            // Add read/write and execute bit to owner among perms
            $owner_perm = (4 | 2) | (1);
            $file_perm  = ($owner_perm << 6) + ($perms << 3) + ($perms << 0);

            // Compute directory permissions, 7 is for all
            $perm = ($perms !== 0) ? ($perms | 1) : $perms;
            $dir_perm = (($owner_perm | 1) << 6) + ($perm << 3) + ($perm << 0);
    
            // Don't chmod links as mostly those require 0777 and that cannot be changed
            if (is_dir(LOG_FILE) || (is_link(LOG_FILE)))
            {
                if (true !== @chmod(LOG_FILE, $dir_perm))
                {
                    print('Filesystem_cannot_change_access_log_file_permissions.');
                }
            }
            else if (is_file(LOG_FILE))
            {
                if (true !== @chmod(LOG_FILE, $file_perm))
                {
                    print('Filesystem_cannot_change_access_log_file_permissions.');
                }
            }
            
            $fopen = @fopen(LOG_FILE, 'ab'); //add more code
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a solution to the problem? You didn't explain your answer. See also [answer]. An unexplained code dump is generally not very useful to other readers.

Comment: Seems it is an answer by AI ... but I believe it will also result in   `print('Filesystem_cannot_change_access_log_file_permissions.');` (AI will not be able to change the file directory permissions of the OP's server directory ... YET)